# Quantum analogue of certain property of compact groups

Tags: harmonic-analysis, topological-groups, quantum-groups, hopf-algebras

Let $\mathcal{A}$  be the category of  $C^*$ algebras. For a group $G$ let $\tilde{G}$ be the space of  all conjugacy classes of $G$.

What is  a precise description of  a *maximal* ,or in some  sense widest as possible, category of  compact topological groups $\mathcal{TG}$ for which the following functor is well defined:

$$\mathcal{F}:\mathcal{FG}\to \mathcal{A} \\ \mathcal{F}(G)=C(\tilde{G}) $$ where $C(\tilde{G})$ is the algebra of  all continuous  functions on **Haussdorf** space $\tilde{G}$ where the latter is equiped with the quotient topology imposed by the natural quotient map  $G\to \tilde{G}$

> Now how can this functor  be  naturally and *maximally* extended to an appropriate category of  quantum groups?